Fundamental group of covering space as the kernel of homomorphism
Consider a surjective homomorphism $\theta: Z_2 * Z_3 \to S_3$ ($S_3$ is the symmetric group on 3 objects) given by mapping the generators to elements of order 2 and 3 in $S_3$ respectively. By constructing a covering space of a 2-complex, show that the kernel of the $\theta$ is a free group on 2 generators.
I know that the cover should be build by considering the action of $S_3$, which is the group of deck translations and I did a similar question corresponding to the 1-complex case (i.e. bouquet of flowers), but am not sure on what to do here and how to visualize/draw this cover.
$\textbf{Edit}:$ I know that a 2-complex with the given fundamental group is $\mathbb{R}P_2 \, \vee  X$ where $X$ is a circle with a 2-cell glued along a degree 3 map. And the number of sheets in the cover will be 6, which is the order of $S_3$, with each element of $S_3$ mapping from one base point to another in the cover.

Have you ever encountered a 2-complex with fundamental group $\mathbb Z_2$? Or $\mathbb Z_3$?

And once you have such complexes, do you know how to put them together to get a complex with fundamental group $\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_3$?

@LeeMosher Yes, a wedge of 2 and a triangle with edges identified (with a disc glued in) should give fundamental group  ℤ2∗ℤ3
